# In Azure Search Service Index document key is not allowing forward slashes

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In my azure search service document index, key field can have a forward slash as this is how legacy systems used to store data. This is not allowed by Azure as when I am trying to insert data using Rest API for indexing data, Azure complains that special characters apart from few like (-,_,=) can only be used, the error suggests to use "allowUnsafeKeys" so that Azure will ignore the check for special character, however I am not sure where to pass this in query parameter or when creating azure index.
I would be glad if someone can help.

Thanks
Pratik